# Delete a row from a table in SQL Server and set message for every condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have set `@message` var, and I want to set those message as per conditions but whenever I execute this code it only returns one message which I set

```
@Message = 'Please provide Topic Name and Topic ID'
```

Please help me - thanks in advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DeleteTopicNameWebAPI
    @InstituteID bigint = 0 ,
    @SubjectID bigint = 0,
    @TopicName nvarchar(200) = null,
    @TopicID bigint = 0
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Message nvarchar(200)
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TopicMaster 
               WHERE TopicID = @TopicID AND TopicName = @TopicName AND InstituteID = @InstituteID)
    BEGIN               
        SET @Message = 'Topic name is present in a system'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Message='Topic Name is not present in a system with Topic ID :'+' '+ Convert(nvarchar (20),@TopicID) + ' And Topic Name :' +' '+@TopicName;
    END
            
    IF @TopicID = 0 AND @TopicName IS NULL
    BEGIN           
        DELETE FROM TopicMaster 
        WHERE InstituteID = @InstituteID  
          AND CategoryID = @SubjectID  
          AND TopicName = @TopicName 
          AND TopicID = @TopicID;

        SET @Message ='Done'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Message = 'Please Provide Topic Name and Topic ID. '
    END
            
    SELECT @Message AS [Message]
END
```

Comment: These messages feel like something that should be returned from a `PRINT` or `THROW`, not a `SELECT`.

Comment: Start over. Your backend logic should not be "prompting" anyone to do anything firstly. And your default of NULL for TopicName is also pointless. To see this, just try supplying a valid ID with NULL for TopicName. Your message var will not be set nor will DELETE work correctly. You are trying to tie the backend deletion logic too closely to the process that wants to delete.

Comment: And if some process attempts to delete a topic that does not exist, then you should consider either throwing an error (since this process **should** be attempting to only do things that are valid) or just do nothing silently. Generally you should not be passing "messsages" that are intended for visual consumption (presumably by a person) from your procedure. You should generally only indicate success or failure from a backend process.

Answer (score 1):

You're overwriting the message.  You should append to it instead:

```
declare @message nvarchar(max) = '';
set @message += 'Now hear this.';
set @message += 'I am hungry.';
```

Then probably print it out if successful or throw it if not. Don't `select` it:

```
print (@message); // or
throw 50000, @message, 1;
```